# Set NULL value in jooq

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jooq

I have an big query and my problem is setting `NULL` values using jooq.
For example, I have this piece of sql query:

```
IF(t.PANEL_ID IS NULL, t.ID, NULL) AS testId
```

If transform this into jooq implementation something like this will come out:

```
when(TEST.PANEL_ID.isNull(), TEST.ID).otherwise(null)).as("testId")
```

but this is ambiguous method call.

I made some research, and find this snippet:

```
DSL.val((String) null)
```

but it didn't work, because it cannot resolve method with `jooq.Param<String>`.

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `NULL` expression must be of the same type as your `TEST.ID` column. I would imagine this is not a `String` column, but some numeric one. Irrespective of the actual data type, you can always create a bind value using the data type of another expression, e.g.

```java
// Bind variable:
DSL.val(null, TEST.ID)

// Inline value / NULL literal
DSL.inline(null, TEST.ID)
```

If you're doing this a lot, you could also extract your own utility like this:

```java
public static <T> util(Field<?> nullable, Field<T> other) {
    return when(nullable.isNull(), other).otherwise(inline(null, other));
}
```

Notice, jOOQ has a built-in method `NVL2` for this purpose:

```
nvl2(TEST.PANEL_ID, inline(null, TEST.ID), TEST.ID).as("testId")
```